# Excel - How do I delete some names in the legend?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, graphing

I want to remove some names that are in the legend of an excel graph. For example, instead of showing all of Series 1, Series 2, Series 3, etc., only Series 1 is mentioned in the legend. Thank you.

Comment: this might help https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-data-series-in-a-chart-ad955a6e-c1db-4550-8664-be059e4bca19

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's important to loop backwards because the position of each entry updates as you delete from 1 to the end i.e 3 becomes 2 if 2 is deleted

```
Option Explicit

Sub legendcleaner()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveChart.Legend
        If .LegendEntries.Count > 1 Then
            For i = .LegendEntries.Count To 2 Step -1
                .LegendEntries(i).Delete
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the fast reply. Is there a way I could do this without having to work on VBA? I have no experience w/ VBA but if this is the only way I could do it, then I will try. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try using the macro recorder and deleting each one by hand and then just running that macro. But I'm pretty sure you should be able to delete each entry one by one by hand if you wanted to